# auth_user table is not created in Django Selenium tests

Tags: django, django-models, selenium, django-testing

I'm using django-selenium to test my Django 1.3 project. The problem is, tests fail at the stage of user authorization, with an error **"No such table: auth_user"**. 
I'm able to create users in the testing code, though.
Is there a way to make Django create the tables for authentification, not only the ones from models.py?
Thanks.

**UPD**. Log says that auth_user table was created, but the error still appears.

**UPD2**. The solution to this problem is to specify TEST_NAME in the settings. Go [here](http://timescapers.com/2011/08/27/django-nose-selenium-a-concise-tutorial/) for the details (it's written for *nose*, but works on other tools as well).

Comment: Have you checked that `django.contrib.auth` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: I'm getting this error in my nose tests that aren't using Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to specify TEST_NAME in the settings. Go [here](http://timescapers.com/2011/08/27/django-nose-selenium-a-concise-tutorial/) for the details (it's written for nose, but works on other tools as well).

Comment: The `TEST_NAME` thing isn't working for me (django 1.6.7) -- http://dpaste.com/10K0XVH